# ``hover state works in inspector but not in the actual browser

Tags: html, css, hover, inspector

I am having issues with some divs who are supposed to change from a background image to a background color when hovered. If you try to run my piece of code I posted below you will find that it works, however i am using the same code on [www.pieterswebdesign.com/desktop/index.html](http://www.pieterswebdesign.com/desktop/index.html) and there if i hover the images on the site nothing happens....

Also when you force the hover state in the inspector it does work...
anybody knows the issue here?

```css
#kijker1div {
  width: 55%;
  padding-bottom: 31.5%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5%;
  background-image: url(images/kijker1.png);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
#kijker2div {
  width: 44.5%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1.25%;
  background-image: url(images/kijker2.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
#kijker3div {
  width: 55%;
  padding-bottom: 37%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -9.25%;
  margin-right: .5%;
  background-image: url(images/kijker3.png);
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}
#kijker4div {
  width: 44.5%;
  padding-bottom: 28.5%;
  margin-top: -.75%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background-image: url(images/kijker4.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
#kijker1div:hover {
  background-color: #3498db;
  background-image: none;
}
#kijker2div:hover {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  background-image: none;
}
#kijker3div:hover {
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  background-image: none;
}
#kijker4div:hover {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  background-image: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="kijker1div" class="kijkerdiv"></div>
  <div id="kijker2div" class="kijkerdiv"></div>
  <div id="kijker3div" class="kijkerdiv"></div>
  <div id="kijker4div" class="kijkerdiv"></div>


</div>
```

Comment: Are u using any .js in that particular html page just remove and then check it I think it's preventing that hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to not clearing the `float`, the following element is "covering" your four tiles so the mouse can't get through.

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the *container*.

Answer (score 0):

The `#kijkerdivtxt1` div is overlapping the above wrapper class that wraps your images (because the wrappers height is not equal to its child elements), which is preventing the hover event from triggering.

You can either set any one of the properties for the wrapper class

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```